# CoreAVC Professional on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, codec, coreavc, kmplayer

Has anyone had any success in getting CoreAVC with Haali Media Splitter playback on Windows 7?

I've been trying both KMPlayer (the Korean one, not the OSS one) and Media Player Classic Home Cinema and it never seems that I'm able to get it to use CoreAVC. I'm using CoreAVC Professional 1.9.0 and the latest version of MPC HC and KMPlayer. I have VLC installed but atleast before it was never even worth trying to get nonVLC codecs working with that.

The video playback I'm targeting is 720P H264 MKV with ASS/SSA subtitles and 720P X264 MKV video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CoreAVC + Haali + Media Player Classic in Windows 7 x64 without any problems. There is probably another codec that is taking priority over CoreAVC. If you have ffdshow insalled, go into the options an set h264 support to disabled. Media Player Classic also has options to set codec priority.

Comment: CoreAVC with SMPlayer in Windows 7 x86, no problem. +1

Answer (score 2):

The 2 players that in my experience work best with CoreAVC are Zoom Player (pro) or Media Player Classic..

You can always use GraphEdit (http://www.digital-digest.com/dvd/downloads/showsoftware_graphedit_141.html) to view and edit what codecs get used...

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere that if you have MPC HC 64Bits installed, you need a 64 Bits decoder, which CORE AVC isn't on the moment